# Event handler even more low-level than acpid?

Tags: keyboard, brightness, acpi, events

Ubuntu 14.04 Netboot didn't support my laptop's display brightness controls out of the box. So first thing I did was fire up `evtest` to check if the correct keycodes (`KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP` and `KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN`) are being generated. Turns out they are, so I went on as follows:

1. Installed `acpid` via `sudo apt-get install acpid`
2. Created a shell script for controlling the display brightness akin to `echo 500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` and placed it in `/etc/acpi`
3. Created an event handler in `etc/acpi/events` to tie up the BRIGHTNESSUP and BRIGHTNESSDOWN events (as reported by `acpi_listen`) to the shell script in #2.

Is the above procedure the usual way of supporting laptop function keys (brightness, volume, wlan on/off, mute, etc.)? Or is there a more low-level mechanism for handling such events? Because I noticed that even before installing `acpid`, my laptop's power button was already working. So at that time, what part of Ubuntu responded to the power button event?